# In TYPO3, using RealURL, how do translated URLs work

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl

I have added an HMENU of type language, and some translations, and I can click the menu buttons to see the translations. However, there are a few things which are broken, and I'd like to get a more fundamental understanding.

The first thing which is strange: in the language menu the HREF for untranslated pages looks like e.g. `/en/my-page`, whereas the HREF for translated pages looks like `/my-page?L=1`. Wbat's going on here? I've put in the *preVars* section described in https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Notes-for-Integrators#configuring-languages. I would prefer it if the user never had to see the ?L=x query string parameter.

*Edit: I have fixed this first issue by correcting my domain record from `https://www.my.domain.com` to `www.my.domain.com`, then clearing out the realurl database tables.*

My second problem is my other normal HMENUs. The text in these is getting translated correctly, but the links are not - you end up going back to the default language every time you navigate.

Any help much appreciated.

I have tried all of the following:

- 'Clear all cache' button
- 'Clear PHP opcode cache' button
- rm -rf /var/www/typo3temp/*
- Delete contents of all the tx_realurl tables in the database

My TypoScript:

```
config.doctype = html5
config.absRefPrefix = /
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1

## config.sys_language_overlay = 1 # I don't actually know what this does!
config.linkVars = L(0-9) # Make the language link variables work.

## Defaults
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_GB.utf8
config.htmlTag_langKey = en-GB.utf8
config.sys_language_uid = 0

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.language = da
config.locale_all = da_DA.utf8
config.htmlTag_langKey = da-DA.utf8
config.sys_language_uid = 1

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE.utf8
config.htmlTag_langKey = de-DE.utf8
config.sys_language_uid = 2

## There's no 3

[globalVar = GP:L = 4]
config.language = es
config.locale_all = es_ES.utf8
config.htmlTag_langKey = es-ES.utf8
config.sys_language_uid = 4

## There's no 5

[globalVar = GP:L = 6]
config.language = lv
config.locale_all = lv_LV.utf8
config.htmlTag_langKey = lv-LV.utf8
config.sys_language_uid = 6

[globalVar = GP:L = 7]
config.language = ro
config.locale_all = ro_RO.utf8
config.htmlTag_langKey = ro-RO.utf8
config.sys_language_uid = 7

[globalVar = GP:L = 8]
config.language = pl
config.locale_all = pl_PL.utf8
config.htmlTag_langKey = pl-PL.utf8
config.sys_language_uid = 8

[globalVar = GP:L = 9]
config.language = pt
config.locale_all = pt_PT.utf8
config.htmlTag_langKey = pt-PT.utf8
config.sys_language_uid = 9

[END]

## Language Menu
lib.language_menu = HMENU
lib.language_menu {
  special = language
  special.value = 0,1,2,4,6,7,8,9
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
      wrap = <ul class="language-menu">|</ul>
      noBlur = 1
      NO = 1
      NO {
         linkWrap = <li>|</li>
         stdWrap.override = En || Da || De || Es || Lv || Ro || Pl || Pt
      }

      ACT < .NO
      ACT {
          linkWrap = <li class="active">|</li>
      }

      # NO + Translation doesn't exist
      USERDEF1 < .NO
      # USERDEF1.doNotLinkIt = 1

      # ACT + Translation doesn't exist
      USERDEF2 < .ACT
      # USERDEF2.doNotLinkIt = 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this happens with typo3 cache. You need to clear the all realurl table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `config.linkVars` to keep the language GET parameter in all links: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#linkvars

Example (if you only have two languages):

```
config.linkVars = L(0-1)
```

Comment: I've already included this. I will add my config to the question.

Comment: in his case it should be:
`config.linkVars = L(0-2),L(4),L(6-9) `

Answer (score 1):

if realUrl does not render links like 
`/<lng>/mypage.html` and only `mypage.html?L=<2>`

- check the path to your realurl config file, /see extension manager -> real Url -> setings where realurl is looking for it
- check settings in extension manager realurl : is autoconfig enabled  ?
- check the domain settings records (sometimes rearl needs a domain
  record set)
- check if the page with documentroot has the setting is document Root (helps realurl to generate a working realUrl autoconfig.

if you start from scratch with realurl, removing the autogenerated realurl config file, disable the extension and enablerealurl again sometimes helps after fixing bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried these now, although sadly without success.